# What will be the output of TranscriberDemo.java in Sphinx 4?

Tags: java, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am working on Sphinx 4, TranscriberDemo.java program. I have downloaded the alpha version from https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinx4/5prealpha/
and the following jar files:

sphinx4-data-5prealpha-20160531.163451-9.jar

sphinx4-core-5prealpha-20160531.163425-9.jar

From the link:
https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~sphinx4

My Code is:

```
package transcriber;
import java.io.InputStream;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.StreamSpeechRecognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.adaptation.Stats;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.adaptation.Transform;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.result.WordResult;

/**
* A simple example that shows how to transcribe a continuous audio file that
* has multiple utterances in it.
*/
public class TranscriberDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Loading models...");

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    // Load model from the jar
    configuration
            .setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");

    // You can also load model from folder
    // configuration.setAcousticModelPath("file:en-us");

    configuration
            .setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
    configuration
            .setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");

    StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(
            configuration);
    InputStream stream = TranscriberDemo.class
            .getResourceAsStream("/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/aligner/10001-90210-01803.wav");
    stream.skip(44);

    // Simple recognition with generic model
    recognizer.startRecognition(stream);
    SpeechResult result;
    while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {

        System.out.format("Hypothesis: %s\n", result.getHypothesis());

        System.out.println("List of recognized words and their times:");
        for (WordResult r : result.getWords()) {
            System.out.println(r);
        }

        System.out.println("Best 3 hypothesis:");
        for (String s : result.getNbest(3))
            System.out.println(s);

    }
    recognizer.stopRecognition();

    // Live adaptation to speaker with speaker profiles

    stream = TranscriberDemo.class
            .getResourceAsStream("/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/aligner/10001-90210-01803.wav");
    stream.skip(44);

    // Stats class is used to collect speaker-specific data
    Stats stats = recognizer.createStats(1);
    recognizer.startRecognition(stream);
    while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
        stats.collect(result);
    }
    recognizer.stopRecognition();

    // Transform represents the speech profile
    Transform transform = stats.createTransform();
    recognizer.setTransform(transform);

    // Decode again with updated transform
    stream = TranscriberDemo.class
            .getResourceAsStream("/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/aligner/10001-90210-01803.wav");
    stream.skip(44);
    recognizer.startRecognition(stream);
    while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
        System.out.format("Hypothesis: %s\n", result.getHypothesis());
    }
    recognizer.stopRecognition();

}
}
```

And The Output is:

```
Loading models...
13:36:22.338 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: *+NSN+
13:36:22.338 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: *+SPN+
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: AA
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: AE
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: AH
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: AO
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: AW
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: AY
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: B
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: CH
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: D
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: DH
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: EH
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: ER
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: EY
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: F
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: G
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: HH
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: IH
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: IY
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: JH
13:36:22.348 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: K
13:36:22.358 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: L
13:36:22.358 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: M
13:36:22.358 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: N
13:36:22.358 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: NG
13:36:22.358 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: OW
13:36:22.358 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: OY
13:36:22.358 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: P
13:36:22.358 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: R
13:36:22.358 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: S
13:36:22.358 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: SH
13:36:22.358 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: T
13:36:22.358 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: TH
13:36:22.368 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: UH
13:36:22.368 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: UW
13:36:22.368 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: V
13:36:22.368 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: W
13:36:22.368 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: Y
13:36:22.368 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: Z
13:36:22.368 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: ZH
13:36:24.507 INFO autoCepstrum         Cepstrum component auto-configured as      follows: autoCepstrum {MelFrequencyFilterBank, Denoise,   DiscreteCosineTransform2, Lifter}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at transcriber.TranscriberDemo.main(TranscriberDemo.java:50)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

I need some help to run this program properly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give me a feedback

Answer (score 0):

Put *10001-90210-01803.wav* file inside of *edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.transcriber* package and change the all streams like below:

```
InputStream stream = TranscriberDemo.class
                .getResourceAsStream("10001-90210-01803.wav");
```

You will get these commands

```
Loading models...
Hypothesis: one zero zero zero one
List of recognized words and their times:
{what, 0.776, [820:1080]}
{zero, 0.776, [1090:1490]}
{zero, 0.997, [1500:1910]}
{zero, 0.998, [1920:2280]}
{one, 0.998, [2290:2530]}
Best 3 hypothesis:
<s> what zero zero zero one </s>
<s> what's zero zero zero one </s>
<s> one zero zero zero one </s>
 Hypothesis: nine oh two one oh
List of recognized words and their times:
{<sil>, 0.948, [2830:3910]}
{bad, 0.949, [3920:4140]}
{oh, 1.000, [4150:4250]}
{two, 1.000, [4260:4490]}
{one, 1.000, [4500:4650]}
{oh, 1.000, [4660:4890]}
Best 3 hypothesis:
<s> bad oh two one oh </s>
<s> nine oh two one oh </s>
<s> that oh two one oh </s>  
Hypothesis: cyril one eight sir oh three
List of recognized words and their times:
{<sil>, 1.000, [5030:6240]}
{cyril, 0.999, [6250:6680]}
{one, 0.999, [6690:6860]}
{eight, 0.998, [6870:7090]}
{zero, 0.998, [7100:7460]}
{three, 0.998, [7470:7900]}
Best 3 hypothesis:
<s> zero one eight zero three </s>
<s> cyril one eight sir oh three </s>
<s> cyril one eight zero three </s>
* Decode again with updated transform - Hypothesis: one zero zero zero one
* Decode again with updated transform - Hypothesis: nine oh two one oh
* Decode again with updated transform - Hypothesis: cyril one eight zero three
```